# does apk contain payloads or do I have to add them if I want to share my apps via an apk file?

Tags: android, apk, payload

I wanted to know if I have to add payloads or anything else to apk file if I want others to use it via the apk file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An APK file is an archive that usually contains the following files and directories:

META-INF directory:

MANIFEST.MF: the Manifest file

CERT.RSA: The certificate of the application.

CERT.SF: The list of resources and a SHA-1 digest of the corresponding lines in the MANIFEST.MF file; for example:

Signature-Version: 1.0

Created-By: 1.0 (Android)

SHA1-Digest-Manifest: wxqnEAI0UA5nO5QJ8CGMwjkGGWE=

...

Name: res/layout/exchange_component_back_bottom.xml

SHA1-Digest: eACjMjESj7Zkf0cBFTZ0nqWrt7w=

Name: res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png

SHA1-Digest: DGEqylP8W0n0iV/ZzBx3MW0WGCA=

lib: the directory containing the compiled code that is platform dependent, the directory is split into more directories within it:

armeabi: compiled code for all ARM based processors only

armeabi-v7a: compiled code for all ARMv7 and above based processors only

arm64-v8a: compiled code for all ARMv8 arm64 and above based processors only[8]

x86: compiled code for x86 processors only

x86_64: compiled code for x86 64 processors only

mips: compiled code for MIPS processors only

res: the directory containing resources not compiled into resources.arsc (see below).

assets: a directory containing applications assets, which can be retrieved by 
AssetManager.
AndroidManifest.xml: An additional Android manifest file, describing the name, version, 
access rights, referenced library files for the application. This file may be in Android binary XML that can be converted into human-readable plaintext XML with tools such as AXMLPrinter2, apktool, or Androguard.

classes.dex: The classes compiled in the dex file format understandable by the Dalvik virtual machine and by the Android Runtime.

resources.arsc: a file containing precompiled resources, such as binary XML for example.

So, APK suppose to have all binaries and resources to use your app.